# Node_modules dependencies exist but when i import modules into main.js,it notes that modules are not installed

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am writing about a vue project. I had to use a module called vue-mermaid, I followed the notes that "npm install vue-mermaid" and the Node_modules dependencies exist.  but when I import modules into main.js, it notes that modules  are not installed[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKbLy.png)

Comment: What you show is IDE error. It's not obvious it's real. If the app works, the problem is in IDE

Comment: how do you import the module. because some times you need get rid of `@` or you need to add `@` mark  when you import the module.

Comment: Finnaly i got that it actually the problem is in ide.Thx a lot！